# Vue JS access objects of "parent component's sibling component"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following component structure:
[image: component structure of vue app]

SideHead component has a method, in that method I want to access objects of Incidents and call some function on  them.

In short from a method in "A" i want access objects of "B" and call their method.

I think emitting an event and somehow propagating it might help but I couldn't wire it to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use state management such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to communicate between non parent-child components.

Emitting events to `$root` or an event bus is unreliable (prone to race conditions) and difficult to debug - event captures will "fail" silently. i.e. you will never be informed that an event hasn't been captured.

Answer (score -1):

1) You must add a ref tag for every compononent.
`<app ref="App">`, 
`<index ref="Index">`, 
`<incidents ref="Incidents">`, 
`<incident-by-prio ref="IncidentByPrio">`

And call it from root A component like this way:

`this.$root.$refs.App.$refs.Index.$refs.Incidents.$refs.IncidentsByPrio.SomeMethod()`

**Edit 1:**

2) Emit an event from the Component A on the root.

Component A

`this.$root.$emit('SomeEvent', {...});`

Catch this event in your target component:

`this.$root.$on('SomeEvent', () => {...});`